# How could you represent the possible case selections on deal or no deal as an ADT?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Im an algorithmics student and I am having trouble understanding how to represent decisions with an ADT. I think it should be a graph but I'm not sure what it would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like a [descision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). It should have a root node and split  off at every possible descision. It will be a tree graph ADT, something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+tree&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRnq63rfvgAhVFWH0KHbSpCzsQ_AUIDigB&biw=1440&bih=798#imgrc=KNDnyLeKkgbrlM:).